# Apache Camel: How to catch exception from setProperty- Exchange?

Tags: apache-camel

In following method; getHumanResourcePort throws exception

```
.setProperty("humanResourcesService")
                .exchange( d->  HumanResourcesUtil.getHumanResourcePort("INT04"))
```

There is global onException on whole route. But it is asking to catch this.
any idea of fiing same

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar:

```
onException(Exception.class) // global exception 
        .handled(true)
        //somelogic
        .end();
onException(SomeException.class) // HumanResourcesUtil.getHumanResourcePort exception
        .handled(true)
        //some other logic as well as you can throw another custom exception 
        .end();
```

please refer to the [docs](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/exception-clause.html)